# Ubuntu 16.04.6 VirtualBox environment cannot access internet

Tags: 16.04

I have just installed virtualbox and set up ubuntu16.04.6 amd32 on it.

I am having trouble accessing the internet from inside the virtualbox. Could anyone give me any ideas as to why this may be / how to fix it?

I have tried all possible options available on various links by NAT, NAT Gateway, bridging. however no luck. everytime i get loop back IP only.

my environment: Windows 10 64bit, Ubuntu 32bit, Wifi connected (sharing enabled)

[image]

[image]

Comment: You've tagged 14.04 (and EOL & thus off-topic release), however I'd look at your host setup & config.  ie. Ubuntu may not see a NIC because the host has denied the guest access to it.   (*fyi:  AMD created the 64bit we all use today thus it's called amd64;  intel created the 32bit x86 so it's not called amd32*)

Comment: @guiverc thanks for your prompt reply. How  can i enable the access from host to guest. I also don't see 64bit option while creating a VM. only option i was getting is 32bit

Comment: You are asking configuration issues which are specific to VirtualBox on your windows 10 host, which is off-topic on this site.  Firstly ensure you have the x86_64 (amd64) version of VirtualBox as I've seen many users download a 32bit only version that seems to be offered at times for windows (on that restricted version 32bit is all that can be run).

Comment: able to resolve this after copying the Host Wifi MAC Address and giving it the same to VM